# How do I display number of debit and credit transactions?

Tags: java

I am working on a simple transaction project and it's my first time writing in Java so this are the snippets:

```
    private static void loadHistory(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        double totalDebitCount = calculateTotalCountByType(transactions, TransactionType.DEBIT);
        double totalCreditCount = calculateTotalCountByType(transactions, TransactionType.CREDIT);

        System.out.println("There are " + totalCreditCount + "transactions in the database");
        System.out.println();

        for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
            System.out.println(transaction.toString());
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Total count for all debit transactions is" + totalDebitCount);
        System.out.println("Total count for all credit transactions is " + totalCreditCount);
    }
```

and the second one:

```
    public static double calculateTotalCountByType(List<Transaction> transactions, TransactionType type) {
        double total = 0;
        for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
            if (transaction.type == type) {
                total = total + transaction.quantity * transaction.exchangeRate;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

by the way, I don't need exchangeRate*quantity at all so that can be just cut out

Comment: it's not clear what you're saying. you can display it however you want. Print themthe way you're doing or work with a process that has a gui and display that way. Move this to Android for example. your options are pretty broad.

Comment: @CayceK I'm sorry wrote question incorrectly. I edited it now.

Comment: Not sure what is your output but I'd put some brackets to the line that counts the transactions by type> So your line `total = total + transaction.quantity * transaction.exchangeRate;` should be `total = total + (transaction.quantity * transaction.exchangeRate);` or even better `total += transaction.quantity * transaction.exchangeRate;`

Comment: @corneliu thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need to display number of debit and credit transactions separately

Answer (score 3):

Your code currently calculates the ***sum*** of transaction ***amounts*** by type

```
total = total + transaction.quantity; // Ignoring exchange rate
```

If all you want is counts, this should be

```
total = total + 1
```

and the return value should be an `int`, not a `double`.

Side Note: NEVER use floating point for financial amounts.  Floating point suffers from loss of precision in certain operations.  ALWAYS use a lossless format such as `BigDecimal`.

Comment: The point about not using floats/doubles for currency is on I wholeheartedly agree with, an alternative is to store cents in an `int` or `long`

Comment: I was going to mention using scaled units, but that's what `BigDecimal` does anyway, and it can be hard to get right doing it yourself.

Comment: @JimGarrison yeah I want to output number of transactions, but credit and debit seperately, for exlample: 2 debit and 3 credit transactions completed